# Adicionando botoões avançar e retorceder em slide

Tags: javascript, html5

Galera fiz um código java script que muda o `background-image` do meu `<header>` no site porem gostaria de saber se nele da para adicionar cursor de next(>) e previous(<) para mudar as imagens quando clicar neles já esta mudando autômaticamante mais gostaria de implementar o essa opção.

JS:

```
var images=new Array('img/bg-header.jpg','img/bg-header-2.jpg');
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('.header')
        .css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
        .fadeIn(100,function(){
            setTimeout(doSlideshow,4000);
        });
}
```

Comment: Já não plugin pronto com isso?

Comment: @Marconi eu fiz do zero tem algum plugin que me recomenda ?

Comment: Nunca usei algo relacionado, mais [aqui](https://dcrazed.com/free-responsive-jquery-carousel-slider-plugins/) tem varios @Kirito!